# WinForms - Localization - UI controls positions different in additional Culture

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, localization

I did my UI settings.Original language is English. After that I set Localizable property to True. Copied original resx file to frmMain.de-De.resx (for example). Translated all strings. Everything works.

But now I would like to change positions of controls. After that changes are visible **only** for original/primary Culture (En). When I change Culture to de-De then UI controls are on the "old positions"(?!)

Is this normal behaviour? :O I'm unable to change controls positions on my form after localization?

Can someone explain me this and give some best solution. I really have to change UI design but I don't want to manual copy all translated strings again.

If my description is not clear then I can post source code, just please let me know. I use VS 2008.

Greetz!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you select the form itself in the designer, and look at the properties there should be a field Language.

Leave this to default when designing the form: this is the default layout for languages without a specific layout. Now, if you want a different layout or even different labels for another language, select the correct culture from the Language property and start designing your form.

By doing so, making changes to the default (in your case english) layout will not be reflected on the specific language's form. This is the way it is supposed to work, the layout of languages is completely separate.

Comment: Perfect answer for me! It works of course :) Thank you very much and good day :)

Comment: what if the same for needs to be used for diff cultures.i am currently facing similar problem. Some of the controls are not visible in my winform after installing the exe for different culture..